# How to extract fields from kubernetes app logs - efk stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm using FluentD (deployed as DaemonSet) to stream k8s app (containers) logs to elasticsearch.
i want extract specific keys from the 'log' key string in elastic such as logKey: ... or statusCode:..  (inside the 'log' key below)

[Please see the log i'm trying to parse:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMn3x.png)

i saw that i should use FluentD plugin to parse the log before it sent to elastic,
but unfortunately i didn't find a way to do it.

this is my current ConfigMap containers section :

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/app.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you trying [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/8568d1843daababe70763b30ae897388710b2216/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) add-on?
It seems already setup the configure of the fluentd.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8568d1843daababe70763b30ae897388710b2216/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-configmap.yaml

Is your ConfigMap appended to above ConfigMap?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't managed to understand how to parse and extract it out.